# Returned error: The method web3_clientVersion does not exist/is not available

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, openzeppelin

I've been trying to make an upgradeable smart contract using openzeppelin in Harmony blockchain which uses EVM and Solidity...
It is deployable when not using openzeppelin, but when i do, it throws the above error...
And one of my teammates was able to deploy it with no errors...

I don't know if it is the problem with my system, or with Harmony's TruffleProvider... they seem to be trying to fix this and building on this branch https://github.com/harmony-one/sdk/tree/truffle_provider , my teammate was able to finally deploy it, but i'm still getting the same error:

> $ oz deploy
>
> Nothing to compile, all contracts are up to date.
>
> ? Pick a contract to instantiate: Ball
>
> ? Pick a network: stable
>
> ✓ Added contract: Ball
>
> Returned error: The method web3_clientVersion does not exist/is not
> available

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
var web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
```

with

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
```

Adjust the url to the ethereum node address (ganache-cli in my case).

In my case the error was being thrown when calling `web3.version.getNode()`. Found out this method has been replaced by `web3.eth.getNodeInfo()` on web3 v1.0. Tried updating the code to `web3.eth.getNodeInfo()` but is would throw the error *"web3Obj.eth.getNodeInfo is not a function"*. Most likely there was a version conflict between ganashe-cli and metamask web3 providers. Making that change fixed the problem.